# Who creates an instance of controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

After a while, I was successfully able to wire up `Castle Windstor` DI (IOC) to my `WebApi` project.

Now, I am trying to understand `how it works`.

For the above reason,

1. Who creates an instance of a `WebAPI` controller?
2. How to put breakpoint for debugging how `Windstor Castle` actually works?

Just want to say that I am using `VS2012` and `WebAPI 2` if that helps. :)

Comment: Debug Windstor Castle in what way? IIS and ASP .NET would create the WebAPI controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the lifetime of a ASP.NET MVC Controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355139/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-asp-net-mvc-controller)

Comment: @rhughes @Nauman: The given links are talking about `MVC Controller`. Is it the same for `WebAPI` too ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. please see this SO quesiton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494966/difference-between-apicontroller-and-controller-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The microsoft poster [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36476) explains this very clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the direct answers to your questions...

1. MVC engine is responsible for instantiating a controller (Check links in question comments)
2. You need source for Castle windsor: Read DI in .NET by Mark Seemann