# Roles not clearing, app running out of memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

We have finally converted our VS 2008 .NET MVC solution to VS 2012 (yay!), but uncovered a troubling problem.  The web application runs out of memory.  After many hours of investigation, we have uncovered this:

A custom attribute for our controllers is used to verify that the user has the role in question in order to access the feature.  It looks like this:

```
[ScreenAccessAuthorize(Roles = "RoleName.Access"), Prefs]
public class SampleController : SampleBaseController
```

We use an override method to concatenate the role to other possible role names for our system.  It looks like this:

```
public class ScreenAccessAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        string r = "Admin," + Roles + ".Admin," + Roles + ".Access," + Roles;
        Roles = r;
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

There were no problems with this code in the VS 2008 project (targeting 3.5 Framework), but for some reason, the VS 2012 project (targeting 4.5 Framework) runs out of memory in the override function.

The first time the Attribute is run, (in 2012) the value for Roles is "RoleName.Access" and the value for r is "Admin,RoleName.Admin,RoleName.Access,RoleName.Access", but subsequent calls to the attribute override method seem to concatenate the Roles value until the app is out of memory.

Further investigating (in 2012) revealed that if we change controllers, by visiting a different page, the Roles value seems to reset, but if we continuously select features that call methods within the same controller, the value for Roles will grow until we have run out of memory.  Is this some strange kind of caching in MVC4?  Why isn't the value for Roles reset in the attribute?

```
[ScreenAccessAuthorize(Roles = "RoleName.Access"),Prefs]
```

We see that Roles is a property of System.Web.Mvc which has a different version number from MVC3 to MVC4, which is the only difference that we know of.

Can anybody think of why we are having this problem?

Please let me know if you need any more of an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer is hidden deep inside MVC code. The issue stems from the fact that default filter provider, the `FilterAttributeFilterProvider` that builds filter instances for controllers and actions, by default is allowed to **cache** filter instances.

This means that while the default controller factory will always create a new instance of the controller, the filter provider will **not** necessarily create a new instance of the filter, rather it is allowed to reuse cached instance.

One of workarounds is to have the string remapping in the constructor

```
public class ScreenAccessAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public ScreenAccessAuthorize( string Roles )
    {
        int v = 0;
        string r = "Admin," + Roles + ".Admin," + Roles + ".Access," + Roles;
        this.Roles = r;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest( 
        AuthorizationContext filterContext )
    {
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore( HttpContextBase httpContext )
    {
        return base.AuthorizeCore( httpContext );
    }
}
```

but as you can see this requires providing the paramter in an explicit way

```
[ScreenAccessAuthorize("RoleName.Access")
```

rather than

```
[ScreenAccessAuthorize(Roles = "RoleName.Access"), Prefs]
```

where the assignment is done **after** the constructor is invoked (and thus the parameter value would be `null` in the constructor.

Another solution is to **turn off** filter instance caching by replacing the filter provider with a new one that doesn't cache instances. This could be done in `global.asax`

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // remove the one that caches instances by default
        FilterProviders.Providers.Remove( 
           FilterProviders.Providers.Where( 
              p => p is FilterAttributeFilterProvider ).FirstOrDefault() );

        // replace with one that doesn't
        FilterProviders.Providers.Add( new FilterAttributeFilterProvider( false ) );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had implemented a constructor in the filter and explicitly provided the parameter, but the constructor code ran several times for one request, and seemed excessive, although it did prevent the Roles string from growing too large and running out of memory.  I then turned off the instance caching as you suggested.  That solution seemed to work much better.  There are a handful of filters, and the Roles string was growing in each one of them, so turning off the caching worked for all.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact you should probably be doing this in the constructor, rather than in AuthorizeCore, yes.. there is role caching, although i'm not sure when it was added.

The problem here though seems more like the controller itself is not being destroyed and recreated.  Are you, by any chance, doing dependency injection?  Are you using a custom controller factory?  I'd look there.

You could try disabling role caching in the web.config.

```
<roleManager ... cacheRolesInCookie="false"...>
```

Comment: You mostly ask questions rather than provide an answer.

Comment: This is a legacy project, so, we're stuck with what we've got until we make improvements.  We are not using dependency injection, we have no custom controller factory.  This article says the controller is garbage collected sometime after it is created:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355139/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-asp-net-mvc-controller.  But what I don't understand is why we didn't have this problem before we upgraded.  Can you think of anything else?

Comment: @WiktorZychla - actually, I did 3 things.. first, I recommended moving the code to the constructor, second I answered his question that yes, there is role caching, and third I suggested that if he's using DI or a custom controller factory to look at that since it sounded like the controller was somehow being reused.

Comment: I added a constructor to the ScreenAuthorize class that accepts the parameter 'myRole', which I then use to do the appending and then assign to Roles.  I removed the override method that used to execute only once when any controller method was accessed.  The new attribute constructor executes 4 times, but only when loading the main view.  When any other method of the controller is accessed, the constructor code of the attribute does not execute, whereas the override method used to.  Although the Roles string is no longer growing, I am wondering if this is the right solution.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I can post the code as an answer . . . I don't have enough room here in the comments section.  Thank you for the suggestions.  I tried the web.config edit first, but it did not work.

Comment: @codenewbie - edit your question to include addition information.

Comment: @codenewbie - if it's executing multiple times, look for tags that have empty src or href attributes, such as img tags, script tags, etc..  You will need to view the rendered source.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: take a look at my answer. It is the filter provider that caches filter instances by default. Nothing to do with controller instances, nothing to do with DI and a custom controller factory.